# obtaining start index and end index of consecutive numbers in array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want the python to give me the list of list from an array. each list should tell starting index and end index in the array in between the number are continuous.

For example if I have an array

```
d=np.array([0,1,2,4,5,6,9,10,11])
```

I want to get a list

```
([0,2],[3,5],[6,8])
```

The first element `[0,2]` indicates that elements from 0 to 2 in the array `d` are continuous. I thought about using recursive function but it does not feel like the python way of doing it.

Comment: Seems like a simple enough loop...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `np.diff` might be helpful here...

Comment: I have tried only recursive function which actually works but i want to know is there any simple way . the numbers  in the array are sorted already so I created the recursive function to obtain the start and end index delete the first continuous numbers before it calls  itself

Comment: post your recursive function.= as part of your question

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you really don't want to use a simple loop:

```
start_end = np.diff((np.diff(d) == 1) + 0, prepend=0, append=0)
# Look for where it flips from 1 to 0, or 0 to 1.
start_idx = np.where(flip == 1)
end_idx = np.where(flip == -1)
```